# Paypal Express Checkout Shipping Callback

Tags: magento, paypal

We have sent the following question to PayPal's technical support and still no news after 2 weeks. I hope someone here can help us :)

We are currently trying to make PayPal Express Checkout work with Magento.

Our shipping callback script is being called.

If the script sends backs the following response (UPS options only), everything works as expected in PayPal:

```
L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=19.03&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=ups_11&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=United+Parcel+Service+-+UPS+Standard&L_TAXAMT0=5.98&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT1=false&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT1=23.42&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL1=ups_13&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME1=United+Parcel+Service+-+UPS+Next+Day+Air+Saver&L_TAXAMT1=5.98&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT2=false&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT2=28.07&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL2=ups_01&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME2=United+Parcel+Service+-+UPS+Express&L_TAXAMT2=5.98&METHOD=CallbackResponse
```

But if we send this response (UPS and rpc for Canada Post) options, PayPal simply ignores our response and displays no shipping options:

```
L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0=true&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0=6.08&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0=rcp_1020&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0=Canada+Post+-+Expedited&L_TAXAMT0=5.19&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT1=false&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT1=14.74&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL1=rcp_1040&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME1=Canada+Post+-+Priority&L_TAXAMT1=5.19&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT2=false&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT2=19.33&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL2=ups_11&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME2=United+Parcel+Service+-+UPS+Standard&L_TAXAMT2=5.19&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT3=false&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT3=25.10&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL3=ups_13&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME3=United+Parcel+Service+-+UPS+Next+Day+Air+Saver&L_TAXAMT3=5.19&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT4=false&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT4=28.21&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL4=ups_01&L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME4=United+Parcel+Service+-+UPS+Express&L_TAXAMT4=5.19&METHOD=CallbackResponse
```

Here is the SetExpressCheckout options that is being sent:

```
[PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
            [AMT] => 39.95
            [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
            [RETURNURL] => {domain url}/paypal/express/return/
            [CANCELURL] => {domain url}/paypal/express/cancel/
            [INVNUM] => 100000009
            [SOLUTIONTYPE] => Sole
            [GIROPAYCANCELURL] => {domain url}/paypal/express/cancel/
            [GIROPAYSUCCESSURL] => {domain url}/checkout/onepage/success/
            [BANKTXNPENDINGURL] => {domain url}/checkout/onepage/success/
            [LOCALECODE] => en_US
            [ITEMAMT] => 39.95
            [TAXAMT] => 0.00
            [SHIPPINGAMT] => 0.00
            [L_NUMBER0] => ABCDEF
            [L_NAME0] => ABCDEF Name
            [L_QTY0] => 1
            [L_AMT0] => 39.95
            [CALLBACK] => {domain url}/paypal/express/shippingOptionsCallback/quote_id/309/
            [CALLBACKTIMEOUT] => 6
            [MAXAMT] => 1038.95
            [L_SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT0] => true
            [L_SHIPPINGOPTIONAMOUNT0] => 0.00
            [L_SHIPPINGOPTIONLABEL0] => no_rate
            [L_SHIPPINGOPTIONNAME0] => N/A
            [L_TAXAMT0] =>
            [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout
            [VERSION] => 72.0
            [USER] => ****
            [PWD] => ****
            [SIGNATURE] => ****
            [BUTTONSOURCE] => Varien_Cart_EC_CA
```

We cannot figure out why PayPal is rejecting our shipping options?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How long is your callback script taking to execute?  PayPal doesn't allow you very long to respond.  Even if you have CALLBACKTIMEOUT set to 6, PayPal may not be allowing you 6 seconds to respond.

Comment: Unfortunately, my experience is the same as what Matt says.  Callback is great, in theory, but it really doesn't give you enough time to actually calculate shipping to be returned. It usually works ok for me if I'm simply pulling shipping numbers from a local database, but if I have to hit 3rd party shipping API's to generate the shipping options it just doesn't have enough time and falls to the default options provided in SEC.

Comment: Just got an answer from PayPal. It's like you say, the callback is taking more than 6 seconds (7-8) as we are calling 2 external APIs. Not sure what to do about it ...